# How could I force a hotpush from Meteor to Cordova?

Tags: cordova, meteor

From time to time Meteor doesn't push updated files to my Cordova application running on real device (Android `5.0`).

How could I force it to re-download **all** (or some specific) files to device, without re-running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my production meteor-cordova applications I use [mdg:reload-on-resume](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:reload-on-resume) . It causes your app to update code on re-opening of the app.